# How to split string to a specific pattern?

Tags: java, string, split

I have address on String with this format: http://171.1.1.1:8080/ , I want to use in the code the ip and the port separately.
I did it in this way. but it's really look like hard code.

```
String[] hostAndPort = address.replace("http://", "").replace("/", "").split(":");
```

I need another idea with a nicer way.

Comment: Suggestion: Use the built-in [`URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) or [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) classes to parse and extract values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the JDK's URI class:

```
final URI uri = URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8080/a/b");
System.out.println(uri.getHost()); // 127.0.0.1
System.out.println(uri.getPort()); // 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the URI, but it's worth pointing out that regexes can help in such situations.